# Entity Framework's one-to-many with buid-in type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am a bit new to EntityFramework and faced the following problem:
I use virtual property to make lazy-load context.

```
public class Faculty
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FacultyIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string FacultyAcronym { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> FacultyStudents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> FacultySubjects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> FacultyCourses { get; set; }

    public Faculty()
    {
        FacultyIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
        FacultyStudents = new List<Student>();
        FacultySubjects = new List<Subject>();
        FacultyCourses = new List<Course>();
    }
 }
```

And it correctly creates 4 tables in database with PKs and FKs.
However, when I did the following:

```
[Table("CourseRecordsTable")]
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CourseIdentifier { get; set; }
    public virtual Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
    public string SubjectCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Guid> AttendeeStudents { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        CourseIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
        AttendeeStudents = new List<Guid>();
    } 

}
```

Here it can't create another table for AttendeeStudents. I think that is happens because I didn't have defined class for Guid as it is build-in type. So, how can I solve this problem? In each Course there is list of attendee students : should I store them as **ICollection of Student**  or as collection **of Student's IDs (Guid)**?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with EF's code-first. But from a database point of view, you'll want to create a new table that exists of just your guids. So create a new class `AttendeeStudent`, add just one property/column `Id` of the type `Guid`. And change your `ICollection<Guid>` to `ICollection<AttendeeStudent>`

Comment: If you change it to be `ICollection<Student>`, EF will create many-to-many relation between `Course` and `Student` with auto link table. If you want it to be one-to-many, then the `Student` must have `Course` property.